# HttpForbiddenHandler and 404

Tags: asp.net, http-status-code-404, security

I am learning about asp.net security pattern and practices. I got a code to deny download of some specific files with given extension using HttpForbiddenHandler. That's OK but now I want to extend this functionality. I want to throw 404 error code when user tries to access some forbidden file.

```
<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" path="*.mdb" type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler" />
```

Comment: why not read the manual ? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815152

Comment: Ya, but I already knew it, but this way user gets a forbidden error message, I want to override this behavior to a next stage so that user cant even make a guess of the forbidden files. Just send  404 for forbidden files too. I know how to do this for existing directories, but don't know how to do it for forbidden files...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Web;

namespace HandlerExample
{
   public class HttpNotFoundHandler : IHttpHandler
   {
      // Override the ProcessRequest method.
      public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
      {
         context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
      }

      // Override the IsReusable property.
      public bool IsReusable
      {
         get { return true; }
      }
   }
}



<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
     <add verb="*" path="*.mdb" type="HandlerExample.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
```